# Initial selection for a DropDownList overriding user selection

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to set an initial selection for a DropDownList by calling: drop.SelectedIndex = 5 in Page_Load.
This works, but then if I change the selection manually and want to save the form, I'm still getting the initial selection instead of the new selection when calling drop.SelectedValue. What's wrong?

Comment: In the page load event check the IsPostback property, and only set the value if it's false.

Comment: Use IsPostBack function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten you check `if(!IsPostback)`. Otherwise you will select the 6th item again on postbacks before the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is triggered (or a button-click event):

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)   // do this only on the initial load and not on postbacks
        dropDwonList1.SelectedIndex = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //set up data here
}
}


   if (Page.IsPostBack)
   {
   //do page reload logic in here
   }


    protected void foo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //get your selected value here
    }
```

Try this code

Answer (score 0):

You should be using if(!IsPostback) in the Page_Load function.

protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    { 
        drop.SelectedIndex = 5;
        //yourcode
    }
}

Through this your problem will be solved